# cpanel redirection still works after deleting htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I set a redirection in cpanel. I then deleted the htaccess file from the server, but the redirectin still takes place.

How can that be? How do I edit the htaccess file that makes the redirection happen? My own changes to the htaccess file (which I deleted) don't work either,

Comment: maybe you need to clear your dns cashe , in windows , type in `cmd ipconfig /flushdns`

Answer (score 0):

In cPanel you should be able to remove the re-direction with the same tool you used to create it. cPanel is funny about having it's files edited.

Answer (score 0):

Removing Redirect entries in cPanel, deleting .htaccess files and ipconfig/flushdns command didn't work for me alone.

In addition to following all 3 steps mentioned above, we will have to clear our browser cache as well to make deleted redirect don't work anymore.